# Controlling Desktop Client with iPhone over Bluetooth

Tags: c#, iphone, bluetooth

Does anybody know any online tutorials about receiving data between a desktop client (in c# mostly) and an iPhone with bluetooth?

How would a C# desktop client connect over bluetooth... by reading the COM Ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand the iPhone will not pair with a PC as a bluetooth device, as an iPhone will only connect to approved device types. There may be some way to "fake" this and have the PC show up as an approved device, though I'm not sure there's a BT stack to do this.

An easier solution (if it meets your requirements) may be to try using the WIFI connection, you can open up a TCP socket between the device and PC fairly easily and push data through it at a high rate. You should be able to do this with an ad-hoc connection (so you don't need a router) though I've never tried it. You might want to look into [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) if you do this.